# R read excel by column names

Tags: r, excel, readxl

So I have a bunch of excel files I want to loop through and read specific, discontinuous columns into a data frame. Using the `readxl` works for the basic stuff like this:

```
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
wb <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
dflist <- list()

for (i in wb){
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(read_excel(i, sheet = "SheetName", skip=3, col_names = TRUE))
}

# now put them into a data frame
data <- ldply(dflist, data.frame, .id = NULL)
```

This works (barely) but the problem is my excel files have about 114 columns and I only want specific ones. Also I do not want to allow `R` to guess the `col_types` because it messes some of them up (eg for a string column, if the first value starts with a number, it tries to interpret the whole column as numeric, and crashes). So my question is: How do I specify specific, discontinuous columns to read? The `range` argument uses the `cell_ranger` package which does not allow for reading discontinuous columns. So any alternative?

Comment: Is it possible for you to save the excel files as csv files and import from them?

Comment: I have over 100 of them, each with multiple sheets so...no :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### .xlsx >>> you can use library `openxlsx`

The `read.xlsx` function from library `openxlsx` has an optional parameter `cols` that takes a numeric index, specifying which columns to read.

It seems it reads all columns as characters if at least one column contains characters.

```
openxlsx::read.xlsx("test.xlsx", cols = c(2,3,6))
```

#### .xls >>> you can use library `XLConnect`

The potential problem is that library `XLConnect` requires library `rJava`, which might be tricky to install on some systems. If you can get it running, the `keep` and `drop` parameters of `readWorksheet()` accept both column names and indices. Parameter `colTypes` deals with column types. This way it works for me:

```
options(java.home = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74\\") #path to jdk
library(rJava)
library(XLConnect)
workbook <- loadWorkbook("test.xls")
readWorksheet(workbook, sheet = "Sheet0", keep = c(1,2,5))
```

Edit:

Library **`readxl`** works well for both .xls and .xlsx if you want to read a range (rectangle) from your excel file. E.g.

```
readxl::read_xls("test.xls", range = "B3:D8")
readxl::read_xls("test.xls", sheet = "Sheet1", range = cell_cols("B:E"))
readxl::read_xlsx("test.xlsx", sheet = 2, range = cell_cols(2:5))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I thought of using that but my files are in `xls` format, not `xlsx` so the package cannot handle that.

Comment: @Alex I updated my answer and added a solution that should work for .xls files.